# updating openssl, now link error with NSSLOW_

Tags: linux, g++, nss

We have centos6 6.5 64bit server.  It had been setup for 32bit development. Our project is statically linked. 
a team member installed the most recent openssl, openssl-devel, and openssl-static 64bit and 32bit i686 libraries.  Nothing else in our setup has been modified.  Now when compiling we get a list of errors similar to

```
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): In function `__md5_crypt_r':
    (.text+0x99): undefined reference to `NSSLOW_Init'
    /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): In function `__md5_crypt_r':
    (.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `NSSLOWHASH_NewContext'
```

we have tried reverting out openssl packages but the error persists
thank you

Comment: "Nothing else in our setup has been modified..." - famous last words ;) I often say them myself just before I shoot myself in the foot.

Comment: likely indeed, for starters we are going on the word of the individual who stated the following were installed
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.i686.rpm
openssl-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64.rpm
openssl-devel-1.0.0-27.el6.i686.rpm
openssl-devel-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64.rpm
openssl-static-1.0.0-27.el6.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/usr/lib/libcrypt.a(md5-crypt.o): In function `__md5_crypt_r':
(.text+0x99): undefined reference to `NSSLOW_Init'
```

That's not part of OpenSSL:

```
openssl-1.0.1f$ grep -r NSSLOW_Init *
openssl-1.0.1f$
```

---

```
libcrypt.a
```

`libcrypt` is part of NSS. NSS is is Mozilla's Network Security Services library. You can read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/NSS.

Comment: Yikes, I should have noticed when the library was `libcrypt.a`.

Comment: apparently libcrypt.a was replaced somewhere in the process.  We had to custom build using some help from

http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.linux.distributions.gobo.general/month=20100601

configuring with 
configure --prefix=glibc-2.12-1.47. el6_2.9.src/glibc-2.12-2-gc4ccff1/binary --host=i686-redhat-linux --build=i686-redhat-linux --enable-static --disable-nss-crypt CC='gcc -Wa,--32 -m32' CXX='g++ -Wa,--32 -m32' CFLAGS='-O2 -march=i686' CXXFLAGS='-O2 -march=i686' LDFLAGS=-m32